# pegando description com EnumDropDownListFor asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Como eu pego a description usando o html helper EnumDropDownListFor do Asp.net MVC 5 ?

Tenho meu enumerador

```
public num Dias {
      [Description("Segunda dia de trabalho")]
      Segunda = 1,
      [Description("Terçadia de trabalho")]
      Terca = 2
}
```

Quando eu uso o html helper do asp.net mvc5

```
 @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => x.Dias);
```

Ele me retorna os valores : "Segunda,Terca", eu gostaria que retornacem os valores da Description no meu select

Comment: Não entendi!? pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: Atualizei Maria, acho que ficou melhor agora

Comment: Agora ficou @Rod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reescrevi, o método static extensivo.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web;
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class MethodsExtensivos
    {
        public static System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListDescriptionFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string label = null, object htmlAttributes = null)            
        {
            TModel model = htmlHelper.ViewData.Model;
            TProperty property = default(TProperty);
            if (model != null)
            {
                Func<TModel, TProperty> func = expression.Compile();
                property = func(model);
            }
            TagBuilder select = new TagBuilder("select");            
            if (htmlAttributes != null)
            {
                System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = htmlAttributes.GetType().GetProperties();
                foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop in properties)
                {
                    select.MergeAttribute(prop.Name, (String)prop.GetValue(htmlAttributes, null));
                }
            }            
            Type type = typeof(TProperty);            
            String[] Names = type.GetEnumNames();
            if (label != null)
            {
                TagBuilder option = new TagBuilder("option");
                option.MergeAttribute("value", "0");
                option.InnerHtml = label;
                select.InnerHtml += option.ToString();
            }            
            foreach(string Name in Names) {
                System.Reflection.MemberInfo info = type.GetMember(Name).FirstOrDefault();
                TagBuilder option = new TagBuilder("option");
                if (property != null && property.ToString().Equals(Name))
                {
                    option.MergeAttribute("selected", "selected");
                }
                option.MergeAttribute("value", ((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(TProperty), Name)).ToString());
                var texto = info.CustomAttributes
                        .Select(x => x.ConstructorArguments.Select(a => a.Value))
                        .FirstOrDefault();
                if (texto != null)
                {
                    option.SetInnerText(texto.FirstOrDefault().ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    option.SetInnerText(Name);
                }
                select.InnerHtml += option.ToString();
            }
            if (!select.Attributes.Where(x => x.Key.ToLower().Equals("id")).Any())
            {
                select.MergeAttribute("id", type.Name);

            }
            if (!select.Attributes.Where(x => x.Key.ToLower().Equals("name")).Any())
            {
                select.MergeAttribute("name", type.Name);
            }
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(select.ToString());
        }            
    }
}
```

Programando esse código:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListDescriptionFor(a => a.Dias)
@Html.EnumDropDownListDescriptionFor(a => a.Dias, "Escolha do Dia da Semana")
@Html.EnumDropDownListDescriptionFor(a => a.Dias, "Escolha do Dia da Semana", new { id="select1", name="select1", css="style1" })
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<select id="Dias" name="Dias">
  <option value="10">Segunda dia de trabalho</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="20">Ter&#231;a dia de trabalho</option>
</select>
<select id="Dias" name="Dias">
  <option value="0">Escolha do Dia da Semana</option>
  <option value="10">Segunda dia de trabalho</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="20">Ter&#231;a dia de trabalho</option>
</select>
<select css="style1" id="select1" name="select1">
  <option value="0">Escolha do Dia da Semana</option>
  <option value="10">Segunda dia de trabalho</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="20">Ter&#231;a dia de trabalho</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Boa solução. Sugiro remover o trecho que atribui valor ao label, pois normalmente os enums são zero-index, e um value="0" seria a primeira opção. Remover essa linha: option.MergeAttribute("value", "0");

Answer (score 8):

Uma alternativa que encontrei é usar a annotation

```
[Display(Name = "Valor")]
```

Nela o próprio Html Helper reconhece os valores, não tendo que fazer nada mais que isso

Comment: Excelente solução... :)

Comment: Essa resposta deveria ter sido marcada como solução.

Comment: Obrigado por compartilhar, excelente solução, simples e prática.

Answer (score 1):

Eu utilizo esse extension method:

```
public static string GetEnumDescription(this Enum value)
{
    FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

    DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
        (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
        false);

    if (attributes != null &&
        attributes.Length > 0)
        return attributes[0].Description;
    else
        return value.ToString();
}
```

Que permite recuperar os valores pra depois popular o dropdown dessa forma:

```
var listaParaDropDown = from EMeuEnum in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EMeuEnum ))
                        select new { Id = e, Nome = e.GetEnumDescription() };
```

Preencha o dropdown a partir dessa lista.